# Is there a way to connect 2 rasberryPi's over wifi for long distance communication?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, connection

I am currently looking to enable 2 RPi's to communicate over the internet for long distances, I plan to write the scripts in python, I would appreciate a list of technologies and concepts that will guide me to accomplish my goal.

Any help is appreciated
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Continuous communication over WIFI: [Sockets library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) (recommended in most cases).
- Periodic communication over WIFI: [Email library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) (alternative libraries exist depending on what you need).
- Periodic communication with no WIFI: [SMS library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python) (alternative libraries exist depending on your needs).
- File transfers: FTP via [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) (preferred) or even a synced [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) file (dropbox works on linux).

* In order to connect sockets/FTP [you will probably need to port forward](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003017/connecting-to-a-python-socket-behind-a-router) or use [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/).